# How to re-enable the lock screen after upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, lock-screen

I ran the managed upgrade on my system and the installer told me the lock screen will be disabled for the upgrade.

It never got re-enabled. How do I do it?

My settings show everything is up and ready for action. But no action. Very sad.

I know some solutions on here recommend switching display managers. But! I can't do things like that. I have work to do.

Comment: Someone please edit my question to put a period after my last sentence. Thank you.

Comment: @UnKNOWn You are the real mvp.